# Link to password reset not getting sent on the email sent by rails action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

i am trying to send a password regeneration link to the email of the user when he clicks on forgot password and enters his email id.

This is the action mailer method that i am using

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base

default from: "myemailid"
def deliver_password_reset_instructions(user)
email = "myemailid"
subject=       "Password Reset Instructions"     
sent_on  =     Time.now  
body={:edit_password_reset_url=>edit_password_reset_url(user.perishable_token)}
mail(:to=>email,:subject=>subject)


end

end
```

And here is the view inside notifier

```
A request to reset your password has been made. If you did not make this request,
simply    ignore this email. If you did make this request just click the link below:

<%= @edit_password_reset_url %>

 If the above URL does not work try copying and pasting it into your browser. 
 If you continue to have problem please feel free to contact us.


 Everything else is getting sent but the link is not sent.

  I cant seem to find out the problem so pls if any one knows how to solve this issue,pls     help.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the URL helpers within your email view:

```
A request to reset  your password ...

<%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.perishable_token) %>

If the above url doesn't work ...
```

You just need to set instance variables in your notifier method for `@user`:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def deliver_password_reset_instructions(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => 'Password Reset Instructions')
  end
end
```

You'll note there's no need to set the sent_on time either. The view has access to any instance variables set within the action method, so setting `@user` is enough. No need for your `body` line.

Comment: i modified my code and removed body and made edit_password_reset_url as an instance variable and it seems to be working now.Thanks for your answer as well.